# How to convert external css properties to inline property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am require to convert the element tag, `css` applied from the style sheet to convert in to inline styles. is it possible? if so how to achieve this?

I require to convert this for converting a `html` document in `pdf` document.

here is the sample :

```
<div id="border">
    <h1>Text <span>sub text</span></h1>
</div>
```

css :

```
div{
    border:2px solid red;
}

    div h1 {
        font-size:2em;
    }

div h1 span {
    color : blue;
}
```

I would like to pick up the styles from each of the element and need to apply in to the `inline` style. once that's done, i have to export to `pdf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of tools for this task. Here are just some of them:

### Online

- http://premailer.dialect.ca
- http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php
- http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/

### Grunt

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-inline-css

### Gulp

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inline-css